# How to change algorithm title format from point(.) to dash(-)

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I am using package {algorithm2e} to write algorithm.
Now I want to alter the algorithm title format with dash(-), for example,
I am writing the first algorithm in chapter 3, so the title of this algorithm is **'Algorithm 3.1:'**, but I want a format like **'Algorithm 3-1:'**. How to deal with it?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[algochapter]{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thealgocf{\csname the\algocf@within\endcsname-\@arabic\c@algocf}% change dash to whatever you prefer
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Alg}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, `\algocf@within` is replaced by `chapter` to produce `\thechapter`.